# Searching for a suitable method to detect peak heights of nanosecond pulses

Tags: adc, pulse, sampling

My goal is to digitize an analog signal and measure the maximum pulse peaks via an ADC device. The signal has the frequency (*pulse-repetition-rate*) of f = 100 kHz. Furthermore, the analog signal consists of narrow pulses that exhibit pulse durations around ~30 ns. In addition, peak voltages of the pulses are not constant and change in time. Below, you can see the illustration of the signal:

*(Note: Actually, pulses are not rectangular-shaped. They have the form of a Gaussian pulse.)*
[image]

The problem is that comparing to the period of the signal, pulse durations are very short. So, I think that it is a real challenge to accurately capture the each pulse and detect their peak voltages via an ADC component. I don't know which ADC meet my requirements to detect pulse amplitudes, since I couldn't decide the required sampling rate and bandwidth of ADC.

I don't want to use GSPS-ADCs, since their prices are really high. Can I use kSPS range ADCs to detect pulse heights? (e.g. only one sample for one pulse) I think this method requires the accurate synchronization of ADC clock to analog signal, am I right?

Can you guys give me some design advice to chose a proper ADC to digitize such a signal?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm a little confused. You have non-rectangular pulses? is this because of a rise and fall time of the signal? or is this the signal anyway? which also changes amplitude? can I ask what it is you want to measure?

Comment: Have you considered using an op-amp based peak detector (e.g. http://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/ltc6244-high-speed-peak-detector.html)?

Comment: @Jak I'm trying to measure the output signal from a photo-detector, whose input signal is nanosecond laser pulses: For example: [link] (http://lightcon.com/uploads/_CGSmartImage/Pharos-duration---20150527-b230e5e2e918ca5ac2b0ba302ce30e34.jpg) The output pulses from the detector have a Gaussian like characteristic similar to the laser pulses.

Comment: Well if that's the case then as Jules said go with a peak detector, have the reference voltage a little lower then your peak and you don't have to use an ADC

Comment: @Jules Yes, I have considered peak detectors also, but I couldn't decide which method (adc, peak detector or etc..) meet my design requirements best, since I am really experienced in this field. Do peak detectors have the ability of extracting the peak of such a narrow signal accurately?

Comment: It's simple: if you don't need to obtain the actual voltage value (the height) of the peak pulse, but only the *presence* of the pulse, don't use an ADC at all. All you need is a fast comparator with a fixed reference voltage, and this will be much easier (and cheaper) to get all this working.

Comment: To simplify:  You need to digitize the amplitude of the peak.  You only need to digitize the peak value when a pulse is detected.  Is that correct?

Comment: There are available GSPS ADCs that store to a short on-chip memory, and then can be read out at low speed, specifically for this sort of problem, like [this for instance](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/adc08b3000.pdf)

Comment: Your photo-detector *might* be able to charge a capacitor with its pulse current to a peak voltage - effectively a pulse integrator. A slower-speed ADC could infer pulse height from two samples: (before pulse, and after pulse). This would require each pulse shape to be identical.

Comment: Useful search term : track and hold circuit.

Comment: @glen_geek: Yes, I believe this is called "charge amplifier" and is commonly used in photodetectors for high energy physics where you need to detect very low level ns-speed light pulses. Typically the pulse from the charge amplifier is then filtered by a gaussian shaper circuit.

Comment: @dim Actually, I need the values of peak voltages of pulses to further process this data for an optimization process. Maybe I can use a peak detector first and then an ADC component to digitize the output of the peak detector.

Comment: @JRE Yes, exactly.

Comment: @Neil_UK Yes, but after all these comments and the researches I made, I realized that even if the ADC component has a sampling rate in GSPS range and store the data in its memory, it is not possible to capture maximum values of every pulses since an ADC component works on a time-based operation and does not detect the peak location. Am I right? May be I can use an ADC after a peak detector circuit.

Comment: @partheniusx With a bare ADC, all you can do is capture, see if you caught a peak, and if not, try again. If you want to capture every peak then thst won't do.

Answer (score 1):

Can you low pass filter the pulses and measure the average?

Are you monitoring some sort of optical process (fluorescence, absorption)? You want to make your measurement not on a single pulse but on a whole load of them.

You can still do ratiometric measurements on the average of pulses.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually, I want to measure the peak heights of each pulse individually and digitize each of them to use in a computer-based process. So, I think the filter+averaging method can't give me the exact amplitudes of each pulse, am I wrong?

Comment: I think that you want to maximize the SNR. (There are applications where you do need the exact amplitude for each pulse but if you end up averaging them up in software then do it in hardware.) Do the analysis - if you digitize each pulse your BW has increased and the cost of the ADC has increased.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffqZzt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Use a Schottky diode HP5082-2514 ???  100 picosecond turnon/off time

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm going to analyze this setup in a simulation environment. By the way, what is the operational name of this circuit? (I mean, is it a _peak detector_ or something else?)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the label at the output of the circuit. It is a _sample and hold_ circuit.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. It is perhaps too late for the OP, but for some new users, it can be useful.

Here is an example of what can be done in "similar" conditions ...
NB: of course, devices must be "adapted" to the needed speed   (delay line, PDL monostable, comparator,  ...).
Property of delay line (when "Load open") is used to double the voltage at the sampler input.
Line delay "time" is big, only to show the principle, but it must be used to synchronize signal delayed with pulse sampler (Pd).

[image]